Pytorch dataloader for image based timeseries
I have a series of images which shows the evolution of a system in time and my aim is to predict the next n-steps forward in time. My issue is how to return a set of say 10 images to predict the next 10 and then continue. With a Pytorch dataloader using say a batch of 30, once I get to image 20 I need to generate the next set of images from the dataloader to perform prediction check.
Plus I need to iterate over the set of images eg 0-10, 1-11, 2-12 etc
This is for an assignment and I am only looking any ideas/ links to similar implementations as I want to write the code myself.
Thanks in advance

So you actually need 0-9 for model input and 10-19 for you loss function comparison, then 1-10 with 11-20, 2-11 with 12-21, etc?

Also, what have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

I tried creating a large array with the data but this runs out of memeory and seemed inefficient. The issue is how to access the next batch from the dataloader while using the current one. Upto item 19 there is no issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can be closed, I found the answer here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataloader-for-a-lstm-model-with-a-sliding-window/22235
